# Codeigniter3: What are the core directories required?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wish to use codeigniter NOT as a framework for building a site, but simply as a backend to handle some php stuff (eg. db in/out, image manipulation, file writing to the server).

In the default download of CodeIgniter3, there are 3 primary directories (*application*, *system*, and *user_guide*). Most of *application* is roughly empty, other than *application/config*; and *user_guide* is surely unnecessary.

So what parts of CodeIgniter3 are needed such that it is functionally complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: All of it

If you want to use just a set of a framework's components, CodeIgniter is not the right pick.

---

Long answer:

In theory: it should be just *system/core/*

But most of that code assumes that you have constants defined in index.php, that you do have an "application" directory (containing "config/" and "views/errors/" subdirectories).

A lot of it also depends on language translations, for which the defaults are in *system/language/*, so you need that too.

Some badly written parts may also depend on a particular *system/libraries/* or *system/helpers/* component.

So while we started with just *system/core/*, you now need all of *system/* and at least some of *application/* (though that can be renamed to something else).

---

CodeIgniter has a monolithic architecture; it is simply not built in a way to allow you to do what you're asking for.
And those are only a few kylobytes of files anyway - it's not 1980 and that's not a problem; unless you actually load the extra components that you don't use, they wouldn't get in the way.